# Share session between domain and sub-domain

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7

We're doing a whitelabelled version of our site, which will be hosted at foo.ourdomain.com.

However we need to ensure session is maintained between www.ourdomain.com and foo.ourdomain.com, as our SSL certificate only covers the main domain.

In practice this means we'll swap to the main domain on our payment pages, which run HTTPS, and then redirect back to the subdomain, after payment.

So the question is: How do we maintain the session when doing so ?

I've tried with `<httpCookies domain=".ourdomain.com" />` in web.config to no avail :-(

Edit: Figured it out now, I lacked domain on my `<forms />` tag to handle login properly.

Comment: Create your own answer please, don't leave the question dangling.

Comment: Done, will accept it ASAP. (Which means tomorrow, as I cannot do it earlier)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I mentioned in my edit, I just lacked the domain attribute on my  tag in web.config.